# How to evaluate an expression in regular expressions' substitution

Tags: regex, perl, expression, substitution

I need to evaluate `($i + 1)` in its cycle. Or to call a subroutine with return value.

```
  my $i = 0;

  my @tags = qw/ something anything everything /;

  until ( $i == scalar @tags ) {

     $tags[$i] =~ s/(.+)/$1 ($i + 1)/;
     $i++;
  }
```

I just got an idea: that I can evaluate it right before that substitution and save it to a variable, which I can then insert, but it seems quite unclean and I would not be able to use it on backreference variables.

Comment: Didn't bother to look, did you? "*A `/e` will cause the replacement portion to be treated as a full-fledged Perl expression and evaluated right then and there.*" Also, `$1 ($i + 1)` is not a valid Perl expression.

Comment: That said, you're making things much more complicated than they need to be.  Appending to a string shouldn't involve `s///`, and iterating over a list shouldn't involve `while`. All you need is `$tags[$_ - 1] .= " ($_)" for 1..@tags;`

Comment: Well, I am really new to Perl and regexp. I have only known /gmi modifiers and didn't really have a clue, that it could be done with another modifier. Also this snippet was very simplified, to not bother you with additional code, which would be only misleading.

Still thanks for that optimisation, I will definitely use it somewhere :)

Comment: The thing is also, that I do not want to concatenate it on every item, it has a condition and I will most likely need to sort that string, while there wont be just once (.+), but something more precise...

Comment: The passage I quoted was from the docs (perlop), and used the very word you used ("evaluate"). Not sure what being new to Perl has to do with anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$tags[$i] =~ s/(.+)/"$1 " . ($i + 1)/e;
```

The `/e` modifier on the end means to evaluate the replacement part. See [`perldoc perlre`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Modifiers). Note that the replacement must be a valid Perl expression.

It may be easier just to append the text:

```
$tags[$i] .= " " . ($i + 1 );
```